# How to display objects in array on screen in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a list of results where each result has the following data: id, title, system, unit.
This data is in the form of an object,
e.g: ({id:1, title: "main engine", system: "ship", unit: "C"}).

Each result has an `onclick` that calls a my `addFunc` function that is a state. This looks like this:

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addFunc = this.addFunc.bind(this);
    this.state = { selectedData:[] }
  }
  addFunc(resultdata) {
    var joined = this.state.selectedData.concat(resultdata);
    this.setState({ selectedData: joined })
    console.log(joined)
  }
```

Currently, each object is added to my `joined` array when clicked, and I can see it in my console. 
I want to display this on the screen

Comment: Hi, Develoweb Co!  Welcome to SO!  Typically, in React, to display something you include it in your `render()` method, have you tried this?

Comment: Hi, Develoweb Co!  Let me know if my answer helped any!  Feedback is always welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried calling `{this.state.selectedData}` in my `render()` method, but this causes an error because my `selectedData` is an array of objects. for example, [{id:1, title: 'title'}, {id:2, title: 'hello'}]. How can I display this kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try displaying your data by using the `render()` method in ReactJS.

```
class Search extends Component {
    // ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.selectedData}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It seems you are storing this to the state as `{ selectedData: joined }`, so this should work fine.  Your constructor correctly initializes the state as so, `this.state = { selectedData:[] }`, so, hopefully this fix works right out of the box.

Find out more about `render()` from the [**ReactJS Docs: Rendering Elements**](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html).

Comment: This produces error, because my `selecteddata` is an array of objects, so I dont think it can just be displayed like this.

Comment: My `selectedData` would look something like this, for example: [{id:1, title: 'title'}, {id:2, title: 'hello'}]